# SwiftUI Previews not updating in Swift Package

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swift-package-manager

Device: Apple Sillicon M1 MacBook Pro, 2021

MacOS Version: Ventura 13.3.1 (a) -> Latest

Xcode Version: 14.3 (14E222b) -> Latest

**My issue**

When using SwiftUI Views in a Swift Package, the preview does not update automatically. When opening the Preview (Command + Option + Enter), the Live Preview shows and correctly displays the contents of the respective view. However, as soon as one starts typing (for example changing a text in the view), the Preview is "frozen" and does not update to show the new changes. This counts for all changes that are made in the SwiftUI View, regardless of getting an error or not.

**Steps to reproduce this issue:**

1. Open up Xcode (Version 14.3 14E22b)
2. Go to File -> New -> Package
3. Enter "MyPackage" as a name and check "Create Git repository on my Mac"
4. Choose a location and click "Create"
5. In the Xcode window, click on "Package.swift" to display the package information
6. Now add "platforms: [.iOS(.v16)]," in line 8 to set the platform to iOS
7. Switch the scheme output on the top of the window from "My Mac" to "Any iOS Device".
8. Create a new SwiftUI View under MyPackage -> Sources -> MyPackage
9. Build the package
10. Open the Preview (Command + Option + Enter)
11. Change the text in line 12 from "Hello, World!" to "Hello, World Debug"
12. Bug: Now the Preview does not show the new change "Hello, World Debug" in the Preview window and is frozen, no matter what you change additionally.

Does anyone have encountered the same problem? Could it be an "Apple Sillicon specific" issue with Xcode? My devices and Xcode are running on the latest software.

I would really appreciate some help.